# What do the symbols < and / mean in this Firefox stack trace?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, stack-trace

I have a JavaScript error that is being thrown in Firefox but not in Chrome. The stack trace in the Console window of the Firefox devtools is shown below. The exceptions occur in [this minified file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/summernote/summernote/develop/dist/summernote.min.js).

**I'm wondering if the symbols `<` and `/` have special meaning in the stack trace**, as I've never seen something like that in a stack trace before. My best guess is that it has something to do with child methods of objects.

[image]

Text Version:

```
TypeError: a is null
    p</G()
    p</Y()
    p</$()
    M</f/this.normalize/a()
    M</f/this.normalize()
    U/this.currentStyle()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You see the symbols `/` and `<` only for anonymous functions.

**The `/` symbol means "nested".** The outer function's display name is on the left of the slash. The best name Firefox come up with for the inner function is on the right. E.g. `fn1/fn2@file.js` means "you are in the function fn2 which is defined inside of function fn1".

```
function fn1() {
    function fn2() {
        // At this line the stack trace in Firefox will look like:
        // fn1/fn2@file.js - function fn2, which is nested in fn1
        // fn1@file.js     - called from function fn1
        // @file.js        - called from global code
    }
}

fn1();
```

**The `<` symbol is used to mark helper functions** and means something like "anonymous function from this scope or closure".

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
// The arrow function will be named as "sum"

const sum = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
// The arrow function will be named as "sum<"
// This means "a helper function used in computing sum"
```

Another example:

```
const fn1 = (function(fn) {
    return function() {
        fn();
    }
}(function() {
    // At this line the stack trace in Firefox will look like:
    // fn1<@file.js - anonymous function from a closure in function fn1
    // fn1@file.js  - called from function fn1
    // @file.js     - called from global code
}));

fn1();
```

An example for both symbols together:

```
function f() {
    var filtered = data.filter(function () {
        // The name for this function is "f/filtered<"
    });

    filtered.forEach(function() {
        // The name for this function is "f/<"
    });
}
```

Few more examples to play with:

- https://jsfiddle.net/8xbk0fhL/
- https://jsfiddle.net/b59fyp02/
- https://jsfiddle.net/2abrL9ep/

**Implementation details**

These symbols are just partial implementation of the (more complex) scheme from http://johnjbarton.github.io/nonymous/index.html

The code that does it: https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/40e889be8ff926e32f7567957f4c316f14f6fbef/js/src/frontend/NameFunctions.cpp#291-306

Thanks to everyone who provided this information in Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1567096